# webbrowser and xmldocument.load uses a different session

Tags: vb.net, session, xmldocument

I need to manipulate word document in my webserver. So to achieve this im loading webpage within the vb.net webbrowser control, using `webbrowser_navigating` event, im parsing all the url request and if it come across with parameter `word_doc` in it, we are cancelling the request and open the word document locally and auto populate the placeholders with xml generated from the server

The problem is when i log on to my application in vb.net webbrowser, it creates a session on successfull login. To replace the placeholder im requesting a php page which will return an xml. Below is the code im using to get the xml from server,

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument
doc.Load("http://mywebsite.com/createxml.php?transaction_id" & trans_id)
```

It returns an empty xml because it is not using the same session and instead it is creating a new session. How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Instead of canceling it in the web browser control, can't you just let it finish loading the document, then read the document data from the control and load it into the `XmlDocument` object using the `doc.LoadXml` method?

Comment: Hi Steven thanks for your time. im just cancelling the request because it has to behave differently when it is used in the normal web browser. ie if you are using this application on a normal web browser, it will takes you a page where you can upload the document after working it locally . if the same application is used within vb.net web browser control, instead of showing the upload page it will open a worddocument and u can manipulate and upload directly .

Comment: Instead of using a single multiform page in this manner couldn't you just create two separate pages for the two different purposes, reference a common library for the shared code, and save yourself all this trouble?